# '~' leading to null results in python script

Tags: regex, python-2.7, csv, null

I am trying to extract a dynamic value (static characters) from a csv file in a specific column and output the value to another csv.

The data element I am trying to extract is '12385730561818101591' from the value '`callback=B~12385730561818101591`' located in a specific column.

I have written the below python script, but the output results are always blank. The regex '`=(~[0-9]+)`' was validated to successfully pull out the '12385730561818101591' value. This was tested on `www.regex101.com`.

When I use this in Python, no results are displayed in the output file. I have a feeling the '~' is causing the error. When I tried searching for '`~`' in the original CSV file, no results were found, but it is there!

Can the community help me with the following:

(1) Determine root cause of no output and validate if '~' is the problem. Could the problem also be the way I'm splitting the rows? I'm not sure if the rows should be split by ';' instead of ','.

```
import csv
import sys
import ast
import re
filename1 = open("example.csv", "w")

with open('example1.csv') as csvfile:

data = None
patterns = '=(~[0-9]+)'
data1= csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in data1:
    var1 = row[57]
    for item in var1.split(','):
        if re.search(patterns, item):
            for data in item:
                if 'common' in data:
                    filename1.write(data + '\n')
filename1.close()
```

Comment: Can you include first 2-3 lines of your csv file?

Comment: The tilde doesn't cause particular problems, your pattern is wrong that's the problem. How do you describe the B after the `=` in your pattern?

Comment: To know what is the delimiter, look at your file.

Answer (score 0):

You regex is wrong for your example :

`=(~[0-9]+)` will never match `callback=B~12385730561818101591` because of the `B` after the `=` and before the `~`.
Also you include the `~` in the capturing group.

Not exatly sure what's your goal but this could work. Give more details if you have more restrictions.

```
=.+~([0-9]+)
```

**EDIT**

Following the new provided information :

```
patterns = '=.+~([0-9]+)'
...
    result = re.search(patterns, item):
    number = result.group(0)
    filename1.write(number + '\n')
...
```

Concerning your line split on the \t (tabulation) you should show an example of the full line

Comment: Hi, my apologies for responding so late. My goal is simply to extract '12345678910235455' from 'callback=B~12345678910235455' and write to a separate CSV file. There are about 5,000 of those 'callback=B~12345678910235455 all with unique numbers, so I wanted to write '12345678910235455' + '\n' to the new CSV file. The columns also appear to be separated by a tab and not a comma. BTW, do you know of any good resources for learning regex. I am a complete beginner at it.

Comment: I have tried replacing for item in var1.split(',') WITH for item in var1.split("\t") and I am still getting null results in the outputted CSV file.

Comment: Also, the full string of within the column that contains 'callback=B~1234567891012' looks like this '/common/navigation/?callback=B~1234567891012'.

Comment: Updated code below. Now it's only printing out '0' + '\n' in each new line: import csv
import sys
import ast
import re
filename1 = open("example.csv", "w")

with open('example.csv') as csvfile:

 data = None
 patterns = '=.+~([0-9]+)'
 data1= csv.reader(csvfile)
 for row in data1:
  var1 = row[57] 
  for item in var1.split("\t"):
   if re.search(patterns, item):
    for data in item:
     if '0' in data:
      filename1.write(data + '\n')
filename1.close()

Comment: Thanks Simon. I ended up figuring it out on Tuesday. I appreciate the help. Do you know how I would output the results so that they are not automatically double spaced? Im using python 2.7. I know 3.0 has a newline='' option with the parameter input of the input file, but that doesn't work in 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Here I have tried to write sample code. Hope this will help you in solving the problem:

```
import re
str="callback=B~12385730561818101591"
rc=re.match(r'.*=B\~([0-9A-Ba-b]+)', str)
print rc.group(1)
```